# If $E(|X|)$ is finite, is $\lim_{n\to\infty} nP(|X|>n)=0$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, probability-inequalities

For a continuous random variable $X$, if $E(|X|)$ is finite, is $\lim_{n\to\infty}n P(|X|>n)=0$?

This is a problem I found on the internet, but I'm not sure whether it holds or not.

I know that $n P(|X|>n)<E(|X|)$ holds by Markov inequality, but I can't show that it goes to 0 as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: (1) Continuity is not needed. (2) Express the expectation as an integral of the survival function $\Pr(|X|\gt n)$. (3) Consider the contrapositive: what would a nonzero limit imply about the expectation?

Comment: @whuber nice exercise! I think I have a correct answer, but since this looks like `self-study`, I don't think I should write it here. Can I create a private chat-room and show you my solution, so that you can tell me if it's correct?

Comment: @Delta This is a case where posting your answer would seem fine to me: the OP has a specific sub-question and does not appear just to be trolling for homework answers.

Comment: @whuber this reminds me of the non-existence of a uniform distribution over the natural numbers -- does this mean that while continuity is not needed here, countable additivity _is_ ?

Comment: Does anyone have a reference for the proof of the converse: if $n^{\alpha + \delta}\mathbb{P}(\lvert X \rvert > n) \to 0$ for some $\delta > 0$ then $\mathbb{E}[\lvert X \rvert^\alpha] < \infty $?

Answer (score 12):

Look at the sequence of random variables $\{Y_n\}$ defined by retaining only large values of $|X|$: $$Y_n:=|X|I(|X|>n).$$ It's clear that $Y_n\ge nI(|X|>n)$, so $$E(Y_n)\ge nP(|X|>n).\tag1$$ Note that $Y_n\to0$ and $|Y_n|\le |X|$ for each $n$. So the LHS of (1) tends to zero  by [dominated convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: I think you mean "RHS" in your final sentence, otherwise, good job!

Comment: @jbowman, s/he means $\mathbb{E}{Y_n} \to 0$ by the dominated convergence theorem (note that $Y_n \to 0$ alone is not sufficient to reach that conclusion).  I added the link to DCT on wikipedia

Comment: @P.Windridge - I didn't read carefully enough, and associated the "So the LHS" with equation 1, instead of with the previous sentence.  My bad.

Comment: Note that $Y_n$ is a random variable. $Y_n\rightarrow 0$ in what sense?

Comment: @YHH The convergence is pointwise: For every $\omega$, $Y_n(\omega)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

I can provide an answer for a continuous random variable (there is surely a more general answer). Let $Y=|X|$:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\int_0^\infty yf_Y(y)\text{d}y=\int_0^n yf_Y(y)\text{d}y+\int_n^\infty yf_Y(y)\text{d}y\ge\int_0^n yf_Y(y)\text{d}y+n\int_n^\infty f_Y(y)\text{d}y=\dots+n\left(F_Y(\infty)-F_Y(n)\right)=\dots+n(1-F_Y(n))=\int_0^n yf_Y(y)\text{d}y+nP(Y\gt n)$$

Thus

$$0\leq nP(Y\gt n)\le\left(\mathbb{E}[Y]-\int_0^n yf_Y(y)\text{d}y\right)$$

Now,since by hypothesis $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ is finite, we have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\mathbb{E}[Y]-\int_0^n yf_Y(y)\text{d}y\right)=\mathbb{E}[Y]-\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^n yf_Y(y)\text{d}y=\mathbb{E}[Y]-\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}nP(Y\gt n)=0$$

by the sandwich theorem.

Comment: @P.Windridge could you please check that also my use of the dominated convergence theorem is correct? I have a quantity, $nP(Y>n)$, which is nonnegative, and not greater than a quantity whose limit is 0, thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}nP(Y>n)=0$ in my application of the theorem. Thanks

Comment: @P.Windridge on second thoughts, I think dominated convergence is not required in my proof. I need monotonicity of the limit, not monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral. Do you agree?

Comment: @DeltaIV- first, to clarify, "$a_n \le b_n \le c_n$ and $a_n, c_n \to l$ implies $b_n\to l$" is NOT the dominated convergence theorem (usually it's called the sandwich theorem).

Comment: @DeltaIV- no, you don't need DCT, MCT is enough  (this includes the possibility that $\mathbb{E} Y = \infty$, but then you can't say $\mathbb{E} Y -\mathbb{E} Y = \infty - \infty = 0$! )

Comment: @P.Windridge thanks to your comments I understood I only need the sandwich theorem. $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ is finite by hypothesis (see OP).  Thanks again for helping me improve my answer!

Comment: No problem.  Btw, I know $E[Y]$ is finite by assumption, I was just explaining where you use that assumption (the MCT itself does not require it, unlike the DCT, which @grand_chat used and I hope you looked at :)).

Comment: @P.Windridge ah, ok! I didn't notice that MCT doesn't require the assumption. I did have a look at the DCT, that's why I thought I didn't need it for my proof :) I pay the price of not having being taught about Lebesgue integration at university...for this reason, I'm used to do probability calculus in terms of pdfs, instead than in terms of measures.

Answer (score 1):

$E\left | X \right |< \infty \Leftrightarrow  E\left | X \right |\mathbb{I}_{\left | X \right |>n}\rightarrow 0$ (uniformly integrable)

$E\left | X \right |=E\left | X \right |\mathbb{I}_{\left | X \right |>n}+E\left | X \right |\mathbb{I}_{\left | X \right |\leq n}$

$E\left | X \right |\mathbb{I}_{\left | X \right |>n}\leq E\left | X \right |< \infty $

$E\left | X \right |\mathbb{I}_{\left | X \right |>n}\geq  nE\mathbb{I}_{\left | X \right |>n}=nP\left (  \left | X \right |>n\right )$

$E\left | X \right |\mathbb{I}_{\left | X \right |>n} \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow nP\left (  \left | X \right |>n\right )\rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow  P\left (  \left | X \right |>n\right )\rightarrow 0$

i.e. $ \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} P\left (  \left | X \right |>n\right )=0$